# Динамическая ширина у input и select

Tags: html, css, input, форма, html-select

Есть форма с полями типа text и `select` со стоящими в линию метками (`label`). Все метки и поля могут иметь различную длину (ну, как всегда в формах). label'ы выравниваются влево, `input` и `select` левым краем примыкают к `label`, и в общем-то цель состоит в том, чтобы выровнять инпуты и селекты по правому краю так, чтобы они как бы растягивались автоматически от конца `label` до правого края контейнера и в итоге имели различную длину, но четкое выравнивание справа. Картинки загружать не дают, попробую тут нарисовать

***Как по умолчанию:***

Метка поля --------------

Более длинная метка поля --------------

Ещё метка поля --------------

***Как нужно мне*:**

Метка поля -------------------------------------

Более длинная метка поля ----------------

Ещё метка поля -------------------------------

Comment: ужасная идея. хотя если это бланки [строгой] отчетности...

Answer (score 3):

Можно например так: http://jsfiddle.net/DdnQ2/

```css
table{
    width:500px;
}
td{
    width:0;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
td.field{
    width:100%;
}
input{
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>слово</label>
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <input/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label>длинное слово</label>
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <input/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Некоторых особо крутых верстальщиков смущает использование таблиц для позиционирования элементов. Чтобы таковые не смущались, можно выполнить рекомендацию w3c и поставить таблицам атрибут role=presentation

Comment: @Елена Левина, прекрасный ответ, более того, бывают ситуации, когда без таблиц не обойтись))

Comment: c css table [короче получилось бы](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/thmLL/)

Comment: Можно по подробнее про role=presentation в контексте таблиц?

Comment: если коротко, то сложилась ситуация, когда использование таблиц для позиционирования элементов возбраняется и считается дурным тоном. Но при этом объективно случаются, хоть и редко, ситуации, когда иначе не сверстать (хотя бывают и ситуации, когда наоборот таблицы лучше верстать дивами). В таких случаях допускается использование таблиц, а для пущей семантичности вёрстки используется атрибут role.

Comment: @eicto, спасибо! Моей первой мыслью было предложить именно вариант без таблиц, но с использованием display: table, только вот испробованные варианты работали некорректно, а завернуть input в label я не догадалась, хотя это и нормальная практика.

Единственное, что лучше использовать не маргин, а border-spacing, тогда не придётся обрезать инпут: http://jsfiddle.net/thmLL/2/

Answer (score 0):

В примере заключен базовый принцип работы универсального решения, которое вы сами сможете легко дополнить необходимыми свойствами и применить к своему проекту:

```css
/* Reset CSS */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.divMain:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.divA {
  float: left;
}
.divB {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.divB input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="divMain">
  <div class="divA" contenteditable="true">
    Я редактируюсь!
  </div>
  <div class="divB">
    <input type="text" placeholder="">
  </div>
</div>
```